# How to render raw html in freemarker?

Tags: java, html, view, freemarker

I have template like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>

<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="800" style="border-collapse: collapse;">

    <p>server response: ${response}</p>
    ...
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

actually server can obtain any response.

In some cases server returns html and freemarker parse it as html and it looks bad.

I want to show user row html with tags and so on like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn HTML auto-escaping on, so `${response}` will not be rendered as HTML (and so that you avoid XSS vulnerabilities). Starting the file with `<#ftl output_format="HTML">` will do that. Though the recommended way is using `ftlh` file extension and then either setting `incompatible_improvements` to at least 2.3.24, or setting `recognize_standard_file_extensions` to `true`.

In case you don't want to use auto-escaping for some reason, you can write `${response?html}`.

As white-space shouldn't be collapsed by the browser, you certainly also want to put that interpolation into a HTML `pre` or `textarea`, or into a `div` with some class that has `white-space: pre-wrap`.

Comment: ${response?html} is my choice